# How to use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route?

Tags: symfony, prestashop

I am getting the folllowing error in Prestashop Admin Panel in the Modules Section which does not allow me to configure any of the modules.

Enabling the "sensio_framework_extra.router.annotations" configuration is deprecated since version 5.2. Set it to false and use the "Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route" annotation from Symfony itself.
Hide context    Show trace

```
[▼
  "exception" => SilencedErrorContext {#5077 ▼
    +count: 1
    -severity: E_USER_DEPRECATED
    trace: {▼
      /home/desigssq/public_html/new17/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/DependencyInjection/SensioFrameworkExtraExtension.php:41 {▼
        › if ($config['router']['annotations']) {
        ›     @trigger_error(sprintf('Enabling the "sensio_framework_extra.router.annotations" configuration is deprecated since version 5.2. Set it to false and use the "%s" annotation from Symfony itself.', \Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route::class), E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        › 
      }
      /home/desigssq/public_html/new17/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:71 {▼
        › 
        ›     $extension->load($config, $tmpContainer);
        › } catch (\Exception $e) {
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `config.yml` file:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    router:
         annotations: false
```

Comment: That SO does not answer the question! That will suppress the warning but it doesn't tell you how to achieve the same result with it turned off.